# How do I decompile a java class file?

Tags: java, decompiler

I understand that similar questions to this have been asked, but non of them have answered how to decompile a java class with java.  I want to make a java decompiler in java but I do not know how to take the contents of a class file and convert it to a java file.

I am quite sure I will be able to open up a jar file and view it's contents, but my question is how do I decompile the class files in the jar?  I do not want a decompiler; I want to make my own.

I am assuming that every compiler for java encrypts the code the same way and I just want to know what that is or how to reverse it.  I do not know much about how java code is compiled, but I am pretty sure it has something to do with the jdk developer kit.

Lets say I have an entire class loaded into a byte array.  How would I convert the byte array to readable code.

I have a java decompiler right now, but it is an executable, so I can not decompile it and see how it is done.

I understand that it will take a lot of information to answer this question, and I have very little knowledge of how Java compiles java file, so if you could point me in the right direction to learn how java compiles stuff.  **Could you simply post links to tutorials or things I should read to learn how to decompile a class or how java compiles classes in the first place?**

Comment: Just flip the bits and twiddle and bam, you've got Java source code. What are you expecting an answer to say? Decompiling a class file to source code is extremely complicated.

Comment: You need to read [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) very carefully. Unfortunately, this question is far too broad so I'm voting to close it.

Comment: You can fairly easily write a clone of *javap*, the class file disassembler.  (I did it once in the space of a few days.)  As suggested, study the JVM spec document, then just read the class file as a file of bytes and decode the bytes per the JVM spec.  Creating a true "decompiler", that will return something resembling the Java source code, is far more challenging -- you'd best study compiler writing techniques first.

Comment: Compilation is not encryption.

Comment: By the way it's wrong that every compiler generates the same bytecode. I know an example when ecj and javac generate even different number of .class-files when compiling the same source, not to mention different synthetic methods with different signatures, etc. So you should be able to deal with compiler-specific behavior as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by investigating the [class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html). Building something to parse its structure and jump in from there.

When you eventually write the code for handling [code attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3) in the class file, all of the bytecode for a given method will be in an array. From there you'd start applying the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf) for how to decompile specific instructions.

There are also [libraries](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/developer-guide.html#algorithms) that provide much of this functionality already and can help you bootstrap yourself.